# Is there an easier way to 'corner-frame' a piece of text?

Tags: expl3, xcoffins

I've written a hodge-podge of LaTeX2e and expl3 to produce the following effect:

[image: output]

What I have is *ugly* and *ideologically incorrect*. I'm looking for a better way to do the same thing.  I think coffins would come in handy here, but I'm not certain how this could be put together.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_clear_new:N \g_jakecv_group_start_box
\hbox_set:Nn \g_jakecv_group_start_box
 {
  \makebox[0pt]{\rule[-40.5pt]{1mm}{\dimexpr40.5pt+1mm\relax}}
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+3mm\relax}{1mm}}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \Position { mmmm } {
  \group_begin:
  \color{black!20!white}
  \smash{\raisebox{1ex}{
      \hspace{\dimexpr -1ex - 1mm\relax}
      \box_use:N \g_jakecv_group_start_box}}
  \group_end:
  \group_begin:
  \par\noindent\large #1 \quad #2 \newline
  \group_end:
  #3 \newline #4
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Position{2020--2025}{Some Position Title}{Some Super Long Organization Name}{Some City, BC}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May be wipet can do it without coffins, just `\pdfliteral{ wi th 5 o m 3 m 46 i c }`.

Comment: We love you, wipet :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coffins were definitely the right answer!  Putting things together like this with relative positions is exactly what the package was created for.

[image: output]

No arbitrary measurements, no guesswork:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_jakecv_position_info_coffin

\NewDocumentCommand \Position { mmmm } {
  \group_begin:
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_jakecv_position_info_coffin {\textwidth} {
    \group_begin:
    \par\noindent\large #1 \quad #2 \newline
    \group_end:
    #3 \newline #4
  }
  \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin {
    \color{black!20!white}
    \rule{1mm} { \dim_eval:n { 4mm +
        \coffin_ht:N \l_jakecv_position_info_coffin }}
  }
  \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn
    \l_jakecv_position_info_coffin {l}{B}
    \l_tmpa_coffin {r}{b}
    {-3mm}{0pt}

  \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin {
    \color{black!20!white}
    \rule{\dim_eval:n { 4mm + \textwidth }}{1mm}
  }
  \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn
    \l_jakecv_position_info_coffin {l}{t}
    \l_tmpa_coffin {l}{b}
    {-4mm}{3mm}

  \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_jakecv_position_info_coffin {l}{t}{0pt}{0pt}
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Position{2020--2025}{Some Position Title}{Some Super Long Organization Name}{Some City, BC}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just want to note that this answer is testimony purely to the usefulness of thinking through your question enough to write it. It's also a very good basic but practical example of how to use coffins :)

Comment: beware `\par\noindent\large #1 \quad #2 \newline
    \group_end:` is setting large text on a normal baseline, you might want to use `\par` not `\newline` (although it's probably safe enough here, restricted to top line)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Whoops, right :) I made this MWE from a much more complex document; a couple things got jumbled around :)